# Почему не изменяет записи в бд?

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php 
session_start();
$bet = $_POST["bet"];
$result = rand (1,2);
$mysqli = new mysqli ("localhost","root","","game");
$mysqli->query("SETNAMES 'utf8'");
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE users.name = '$_SESSION ['login']'");
echo($_SESSION['login']);
$query = "UPDATE `users` SET `money` = '500' WHERE `users`.`name` = '$_SESSION ['login']'";
$money = $_SESSION['money'];
if($result == 1){
  $money = $money + $bet;
}
if($result == 2){
  $money = $money - $bet;
}
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

В чём проблема? Видел такое решение в интернете. Написал, вроде все хорошо, ошибок не выбивает, но ничего не меняет. Почему?
Эта строка отвечает за изменение

```
$query = "UPDATE `users` SET `money` = '500' WHERE `users`.`name` = '$_SESSION ['login']'";
```

Comment: Вы уверены, что в $_SESSION['login'] что-то есть?

Comment: Да. Его же выводит сверху. Там есть echo($_SESSION[`login`]);

Comment: Почему у вас $result то rand(1,2), то результат запроса, какая-то каша получается.

Comment: Попробуйте выполнить этот запрос прямо в базе.

Comment: $login=$_SESSION[login]; `name` = '.$login.'";

Comment: попробовал. не работает ничего. проблема с result исправил, но было понятно что это не влияет на вопрос который я задал.

Answer (score 0):

Как же оно будет работать, если вы просто присваиваете переменной строчку, но запрос не выполняете?

```
$query = "UPDATE `users` SET `money` = '500' WHERE `users`.`name` = '$_SESSION ['login']'";
```

Comment: в век подготовленных запросов советовать такое - моветон

Comment: скажите пожалуйста каким образом данный запрос выполняеться?

Comment: ```$res = $mysqli->query("UPDATE `users` SET `money` = '500' WHERE `users`.`name` = '$_SESSION ['login']'");```